# Regular expression in C# to replace these string checks

Tags: c#, regex

I wish to convert the following code to a regex test where path is a string.

```
path.Contains(".git") || path.Contains("_ReSharper") || path.Contains("\\Bin\\") 
|| path.Contains("\\obj\\") || path.Contains("\\bin\\") || path.Contains("\\ipch\\") 
|| path.Contains("\\.git") || path.EndsWith("\\bin") || path.EndsWith("\\obj") 
|| path.EndsWith("\\Bin") || path.EndsWith("\\ipch");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(\.git|_ReSharper|\\[bB]in\\|\\obj\\|\\ipch\\|\\\.git|\\[bB]in$|\\obj$|\\ipch$)`

A full explanation of all the operators in this regex can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

But basically:

-Metacharacters like `.` and `\` need to be escaped with a backslash to interpret them literally

-`|` means 'match the left OR match the right'. It's like OR for regexes.

-`$` means 'the end of the string must occur right here' (or in multiline regex mode, the end of the line or string)

If you paste this into a C# string, make sure it is either an @"" string (to escape backslashes having special meaning) or double up all the backslashes (akin to what you are doing right now).

edit: shorter version, after noticing that contains `.git` and contains `\.git` are redundant

`(\.git|_ReSharper|\\[bB]in(\\|$)|\\obj(\\|$)|\\ipch(\\|$))`

Comment: +1 for still giving a detailed answer for a negative question.

Comment: You are rock star mate Thank you so much.

Comment: `(abc|edf)` is "abc or edf" or is it "ab, then c or e, then df"?

Comment: @Yorye Nathan: from http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html, "The pipe has the lowest precedence of all operators." So it will be 'abc or edf'. You can experiment in real time on http://www.regexpal.com/ with regexes

Comment: Huh.. I always put way too much parenthesis.

Comment: In general, if in doubt, add more ()s (tho I personally favour going and learning the precedence rules so there is no doubt), but for REs, using (?: and ) instead is saver - doesn't contribute to the grouping offsets.  I.e. in `(ab|ba)(\d)` and `((?:ab)|(?:ba))(\d)`, $1 and $2 map to the same thing, but in `((ab)|(ba))(\d)` $2 is different and now $3 and $4 exist.